# Get credit card history

Tags: security

There are a few sites out there, mint.com, swipely.com, blippy.com, that have total access to your banking and credit information.  You need to give them your userid and password. Once they have that, they are able to access all of your purchase history.

My question: How is this done? Is this a service being provided by the banks? Are they simply logging into your banks web site and scrubbing the pages? Is there a company that provides these tools or does each of these sites write the code in house?

If anyone has some knowledge they are willing to share, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not really coding security related question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it may have changed since the takeover by Intuit, but certainly before that Mint used [Yodlee](http://www.yodlee.com/) to obtain this information.

As I understand it, Yodlee uses [OFX](http://www.ofx.net/) for communicating with financial institutions, but also does some screen scraping.

See [here](http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=1537825) for further info.

Comment: Great answer, you might want to edit the link for yodlee there is an extra - on the end

Comment: They did indeed. Mint's old aggregation was through Yodlee - now Intuit's legacy system. It maybe worth noting that the first link you provided needs some love.